# PHP Simple_html_dom issue

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

The snippet below loops through some web pages, grabs the html and then looks for table.results and gets the plaintext out of the  tags contained in each . $result is ok.

Now I'm trying to get the href value of an  tag that is found in the second  of each . I'd like to include this in the $results array, but I'm not sure how to do this. The third foreach statement gets them but then I need to merge $links with $results. Ideally I'd also get the links in the second foreach statement.

Does anyone know how?

```
$i = 0;
    foreach( $urls as $u )
    {           
        $html = file_get_html($u);

        foreach($html->find('.results tbody tr') as $element)
        {
            $result[$i] = $this->extract($element->plaintext);
            $i++;                   
        }

        foreach($html->find('.results tbody tr a') as $element)
        {
            $links[$i] = $element->href;
            $i++;           
        }                            
    }

    print_r($result); 
    print_r($links); 

    die;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_html($u);
foreach($html->find('.results tbody tr') as $element)
{
  $links = $element->find('a');
  foreach($links as $l) {
    $result[] = $l->href;
  }
  $result[] = $this->extract($element->plaintext);
}
```